# recursion and sorting within c++

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, merge

i did exactly what the pseudo code told me in the book introduction to algorithms and it didn't work

there are two parts that i dont really understand

1-how do u make a recursive function that is a void i mean shouldnt a recursive function always return the last step then what is before it .. it's a void so how would it preform the task

2-merg_sor() was called twice in one function .. do u call that nested recursion ?or what ?? .. and how does it affect the merg function

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void Merg(vector<int> Arr,int start,int middle,int end) 
{
    std::vector<int> left;
    std::vector<int> right;
    for(int i =start;i<(end-start);i++)
    {
        if (i <middle)
        {
            right.push_back(Arr.at(i));
        }
        else
        {
            left.push_back(Arr.at(i));
        }
    }
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    for(int i =start;i<(end-start);i++)
    {
        if(right.at(j)<=Arr.at(i))
        {
            Arr.at(i)=right.at(j);
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            Arr.at(i)=left.at(k);
            k++;
        }
    }
}
void Merg_sort(vector<int> Arr,int start,int end)
{
    if (start <end)
    {
        int middle = (start+end)/2;
        Merg_sort(Arr,start,middle); 
        Merg_sort(Arr,middle+1,end); 
        Merg(Arr,start,middle,end);
    }
}

int main()
{
 vector<int> x;
 for (int i =0;i<8;i++){x.push_back(i);}
 x.at(2)=8;
 Merg_sort(x,0,7);
}
```

Comment: A function that, directly or indirectly, calls itself is the definition of a recursive function. When, where and how many times it calls itself is irrelevant.

Comment: 1) The changes are done in-place. That is, the `Arr` parameter is being modified. 2) That's just recursion. 3) `if (start < end)`

Comment: You should likely pass the vector by reference `vector<int>& Arr` to make the result visible in main.

Comment: +Bo persson .. i did and it says out of range check , however im pretty much puzzled where :\

Comment: @BartvanNierop 2) how so ?? when we visualize it,we actually have two branches in the tree of merge sort .. the code split the right and left in two lines and then there is that one line merge(A,s,m,e) .. how is the left and right branches are affected by the merge .. the right is split so it should go to merg() and the left is also split it should have it's own merge .. but here there is one line for that 4 split vec and one merge

Comment: @BartvanNierop 3) nah i said the merge_sort () not merge.. the base case for it is that it will call it self and do nothing the last time it's called

Comment: A debugger will show you where - the `if (right.at(j) <= Arr.at(i))` rather assumes that `right` has something at i, which it might not.

Comment: If the pseudocode is like that, your book is broken. The merge should compare the elements from `left` and `right` to each other, not to the elements of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

> 1-how do u make a recursive function that is a void i mean shouldnt a recursive function always return the last step then what is before it .. it's a void so how would it preform the task

A function can have side effects. It means, that a function can modify the state of the program. A void function always works by side effects. A void function that doesn't have side effects is completely useless. Whether the function is recursive makes no difference to this question.

> 2-merg_sor() was called twice in one function .. do u call that nested recursion ?or what ??

I'm not sure if it is commonly used term, but I would describe it as *multi-branched recursion*.

> 2 .. and how does it affect the merg function

It doesn't, because it has no side effects.

> i did exactly what the pseudo code told me

Perhaps you didn't interpret the pseudo code correctly. Perhaps the arguments are implicitly *references* in the pseudo-language that you're reading such as they are in languages like python.

Comment: 2) being called twice doesnt that produce 4 arrays that are split from one ??which is in the last step will produce four numbers ,right ?.. ok if so we have only one merg command for merging 2 arrays not the 4 of them but 2 .. how is it executed ?